# Strict Date format validation in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

Below is my java code to validate the date passed. Need to check the date format is in "yyyyMMdd" format. But when passed the date value "2022109" it is considered as "2022 Oct 9" but it should since the input is not in expected format.
Consider, user may tried to give an input as "2022 Jan 9" and missed 0 in front of 1 in the afore mentioned input and entered as "2022109". Now the code considered the date as "2022 Oct 9" which is incorrect. Please assist me on the same.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        dateValidate("2022109");
        dateValidate("2022110");
    }
    
    private static boolean dateValidate(String date) {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        try {
            System.out.println(date);
            DateFormat objDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
            objDateFormat.setLenient(false);
            Date DateValue = objDateFormat.parse(date);
            System.out.println(DateValue);
            returnVal  = true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

Output

```
2022109
Sun Oct 09 00:00:00 GMT 2022
2022110
Unparseable date: "2022110"
```

Comment: Stop using `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`. These are outdated since years. Use classes from the newer `java.tim`package

Comment: @Jens, `java.tim` namespace will resolve the issue?

Comment: That too, @VenkateshR. (Even if it hadn't in itself, using `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` is still strongly discouraged and java.time recommended.)

Comment: @VenkateshR sorry missed an `e` should be `java.time`

Answer (score 2):

Below code resolves the issue.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.ResolverStyle;
import java.time.LocalDate;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (dateValidate("20220110"))
        {
            System.out.println("Valid");
        }
        else
        {System.out.println("In Valid");}
    }
    
    private static boolean dateValidate(String date) {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        try {
            DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMdd");
            LocalDate DateValue = LocalDate.parse(date, parser.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT));
            System.out.println(DateValue);
            returnVal  = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return returnVal;
    }
}
```